# Program fails to open file

Tags: c++, file-handling

The problem is that whenever I pass the file path and run the code it doesn't read the file. Instead it keeps on giving the output "UNABLE TO OPEN FILE".

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    fstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\Users\Muhammad Shaeel\Desktop\CC\Lexical Analyser Code\Lexical Analyser Code\program.txt.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(0);
    }

    inFile.close();

    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: why are you spamming all tags?

Comment: This does not look like it has anything to do with Javascript, or Java, or HTML. Please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that all of that code is relevant to that particular issue?

Comment: can you confirm if the file name is valid "C:\Users\Muhammad Shaeel\Desktop\CC\Lexical Analyser Code\Lexical Analyser Code\program.txt.txt" ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance  i'm really sorry for the tags. i have removed them.

Comment: @Nik the file name is program.txt . it is a text document but in the given code i have passed the whole file path. ive tried writing only the file name which is program.txt but it didn't worked either.

Comment: @MuhammadShaeel in your program i see the file name as "program.txt.txt" and not "program.txt"

Comment: This doesn't look like C, but try `perror("filename");`

Comment: @Nik yes the file name is program.txt and the other txt is the file extension which is copied when i copy the file path

Comment: When writing a question, please take some time to consider a good title. Yours is horribly bad.

Comment: There is no such thing as "extension which is copied when I copy the file path". Do you have windows settings so that it hides known file extensions and that's why you have ".txt" twice?

Comment: Backslash \ is the escape character in string literals, so if you want to have an actual backslash in the string you need to escape it: "C:\\Users\\Muhammad Shaeel\\Desktop\\CC\\Lexical Analyser Code\\Lexical Analyser Code\\program.txt.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In string literals, the "\" slash is the escape character.  In order for your string literal to work properly you need to escape each "\" with the "\".  In other words, replace each "\" with two slashes like so:

```
inFile.open("C:\\Users\\Muhammad Shaeel\\Desktop\\CC\\Lexical Analyser Code\\Lexical Analyser Code\\program.txt");
```